# finding min value and its index in 2D array in c#

Tags: c#, arrays, 2d, min

I am trying to find the min value and it index in an array which is defined as      below:

```
double[,] Neighbour_Array=new double [4,500];
```

what is the shortest way ? could you help me please ?

Comment: In case of arbitrary array, you have to scan the array

Comment: Forget the shortest way. Show us what you have done so far. Have you managed to do it the longest way yet?

Comment: @Mahdieh please [edit] post instead of posting code as comments.

Answer (score 1):

In general case, for an arbitrary array, you have to scan the entire array:

```
  double[,] Neighbour_Array = new double[4, 500];

  ...

  double minValue = double.PositiveInfinity;
  int minFirstIndex = -1;
  int minSecondIndex = -1;

  // Comparison with 0 is faster than with GetLength()
  for (int i = Neighbour_Array.GetLength(0) - 1; i >= 0; --i)
    for (int j = Neighbour_Array.GetLength(1) - 1; j >= 0; --j) {
      double value = Neighbour_Array[i, j];

      if (value <= minValue) {
        minFirstIndex = i;
        minSecondIndex = j;

        minValue = value;
      }
    }
```

**Edit:** In case you want to find out the min value of the `Neighbour_Array[2,i]` subarray (please, see comments below) you can simplify the code (drop one loop) into

```
     double minValue = double.PositiveInfinity;
     int minIndex = -1; 

     // Comparison with 0 is faster than with GetLength()
     for (int i = Neighbour_Array.GetLength(1) - 1; i >= 0; --i) {
       // please notice, that the 1st index is fixed 
       double value = Neighbour_Array[2, i];

       if (value <= minValue) {
         minIndex = i;

         minValue = value;
       }
     }
```

Comment: you are right, I forgot to mention that I am trying to find the min value in second dimension of array, I mean in all Neighbour_Array[2,i] . thanks for your answer .

Comment: @Mahdieh please don't use 2d arrays to fake list of classes... At very least don't post such questions for public - use `class Pos {double x,y,z,v} ;Pos[500];` or something along this lines for publicly visible code.

Answer (score 0):

I wouldn't say it's efficient, but it's the shortest amount of code I could think of:

```
var len = neighbors.GetLength(1);
var flatten = neighbors.Cast<double>();
var max = flatten.Max();
var maxes = flatten
   .Select((v, i) => new { v, i1=i/len, i2=i-(len*(i/len)) })
   .Where(n => n.v == max);
```

It returns ALL values and indexes that equal the max value though.
So if your array has two 5's in it and 5 is the max value, it will return the value and index of both of them.